# Nested Loop Dataframe python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, nested-loops

I wanted to perform a calculation of the summed costs using the values for 1W, country and cars 0 and add that to 1M cars 0 doing the same for cars 1,2,...,10. then doing the same for 1W and 3M etc. I used nested loops as shown below in the code but this takes too long. Is there a possibility using directly pandas instead performing nested loops?

The combination should be like:

> ```
> USD:
> 1W and 1M
> 1W and 3M
> 1W and 6M
> 1W and 1Y
>
> and
> 1M and 3M
> 1M and 6M
> 1M and 1Y
>
> and
> 3M and 6M
> 3M and 1Y
>
> and
> 6M and 1Y
> ```

```
import pandas as pd

csv_loader = pd.read_csv('Cars.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()

for current_date in csv_loader.index.unique():
    print('calculating date: ' +str(current_date))
    for index, row in index_data.iterrows():
        if index == current_date:

            for index2, row2 in index_data.iterrows():
                if index2 == current_date:
```

My CSV file looks like the following:

> ```
> fact_date;Cars;Costs;Country;Car;Rental_Duration
> 2017-07-14;0;157.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;1;122.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;2;122.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;3;102.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;4;153.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;5;130.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;6;151.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;7;132.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;8;153.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;9;191.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;10;131.00;USD;Ford;1W
> 2017-07-14;0;571.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;1;526.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;2;568.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;3;546.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;4;593.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;5;541.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;6;536.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;7;532.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;8;537.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;9;582.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;10;523.00;USD;Ford;1M
> 2017-07-14;0;679.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;1;641.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;2;622.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;3;654.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;4;655.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;5;635.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;6;623.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;7;678.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;8;689.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;9;694.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;10;625.00;USD;Ford;3M
> 2017-07-14;0;726.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;1;718.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;2;770.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;3;793.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;4;704.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;5;739.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;6;785.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;7;701.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;8;718.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;9;714.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;10;788.00;USD;Ford;6M
> 2017-07-14;0;992.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;1;935.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;2;981.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;3;955.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;4;920.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;5;978.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;6;943.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;7;911.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;8;969.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;9;922.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> 2017-07-14;10;978.00;USD;Ford;1Y
> ```

The output I expect is the following:

> ```
> fact_date Cars    Costs_Total Car Country Rental_Duration
> 2017-07-14    0   728 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    1   648 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    2   690 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    3   648 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    4   746 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    5   671 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    6   687 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    7   664 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    8   690 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    9   773 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    10  654 Ford    USD 1W_1M
> 2017-07-14    0   836 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    1   763 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    2   744 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    3   756 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    4   808 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    5   765 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    6   774 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    7   810 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    8   842 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    9   885 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    10  756 Ford    USD 1W_3M
> 2017-07-14    0   883 Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    1   840 Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    2   892 Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    3   895 Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    4   857 Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    5   869.00  Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    6   936.00  Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    7   833.00  Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    8   871.00  Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    9   905.00  Ford    USD 1W_6M
> 2017-07-14    10  919.00  Ford    USD 1W_6M
> ```

Comment: Are you asking if you can conditionally filter a dataframe based on column values? For example: `df[df['Rental_Duration'].isin(['1W','3M'])]`

Comment: this does not directly answer your question, but based on my understanding, you may want to change `Rental_Duration` to `Rental_Start` with a start date, and calculate the duration on the fly

Comment: @rahlf23, no I wanted more to have the sum of the costs for the rental duration 1W and 1M etc. and then store it. Is it clearer?

Comment: @JeffXiao, no I wanted more to have the sum of the costs for the rental duration 1W and 1M etc. and then store it. Is it clearer?